# My web browser won't store the cookie from the response header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cookies, cross-domain, angular7

I have an API located at http://localhost:57780. 
When I attempt to call the login endpoint from my client (http://localhost:4200), I receive my cookie in the response header AND it is successfully stored in the browsers cookies.

Now, here is my issue: Using the same API, I now call the login endpoint from my client at a different DOMAIN (http://127.0.0.1:4200). 
I still successfully receive my cookie in the response header ALTHOUGH the browser is not storing this cookie.

I am using the HTTP interceptor so that each call has withCredentials set to true.
I have also set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to AllowAnyOrigin.

What am I doing wrong?
P.S: This is my first stackOverflow post so any tips would be greatly appreciated :)